# Wordpress / PHP - Cache custom queries?

Tags: php, performance, wordpress, caching

So I'm making a plugin that gets a set of posts (using wp_query), and it does this every time you refresh a page.

Can I cache the query results so the page gets generated faster?
If so, how do I do it? because [WP_cache](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Cache) functions don't work even if I enable cache in the config file.

A alternative to wp_cache seem to be [transients](http://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API). but the transient data is too stored in the database so isn't that the same as using wp_query (both access the database anyway)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about something like [DB Cache Reloaded](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/db-cache-reloaded/)? I believe it lets you cache all queries that are run.